# Initializing object of a class inside another class

Tags: c++

I have a class `MySeqBuildBlockModule` that I am inheriting from: `public SeqBuildBlock`.
 Other than constructor and destructor, this class `MySeqBuildBlockModule` has a method: `prep`.

```
class MySeqBuildBlockModule: public SeqBuildBlock
{
    friend class SeqBuildBlockIRns;
    public:
        MySeqBuildBlockModule (SBBList* pSBBList0, long TI1_In, long TI2_In)    // more arguements in this constructor of derived class
        : SeqBuildBlock (pSBBList0)
        {
            TI1 = TI1_In;  //in us
            TI2 = TI2_In;  //in us
            pSBBList2 = pSBBList0;
            //SeqBuildBlockIRns myIRns_3(pSBBList2);        //Defined in libSBB.h
        }
        //~MySeqBuildBlockModule(){}
        virtual bool prep (MrProt* pMrProt, SeqLim* pSeqLim, SeqExpo* pSeqExpo);
        virtual bool run  (MrProt* pMrProt, SeqLim* pSeqLim, SeqExpo* pSeqExpo, sSLICE_POS* pSLC);  
    protected:

    private:
        long TI1;  //in us
        long TI2;  //in us
        SBBList* pSBBList2;
        SeqBuildBlockIRns myIRns_3(pSBBList2);                                      // Line 106
};

bool MySeqBuildBlockModule::prep(MrProt* pMrProt, SeqLim* pSeqLim, SeqExpo* pSeqExpo)
{
    NLS_STATUS    lStatus;
    double dEnergyAllSBBs_DK = myIRns_3.getEnergyPerRequest();                      //Line 113

    // Now we prepare:
    lStatus = pSBBList->prepSBBAll(pMrProt, pSeqLim, pSeqExpo, &dEnergyAllSBBs_DK); // Line 116
    if (lStatus ) {
        cout << "DK: An error has occurred while preparing SBBs"<< endl;
    }
    return lStatus;
}
```

I would have like to intiantiate an object "`myIRns_3`" of a class defined in third party library

```
SeqBuildBlockIRns myIRns_3(pSBBList2);
```

and would like to access it from the prep function as:

```
double dEnergyAllSBBs_DK = myIRns_3.getEnergyPerRequest();
```

I tried to instantiate following in either private section or in constructor; but w/o any success:

```
SeqBuildBlockIRns myIRns_3(pSBBList2);
```

**ERRORS** encountered:

When I tried to do it inside the constructor, I get the following errors:

```
MySBBModule.h(113) : error C2065: 'myIRns_3' : undeclared identifier
MySBBModule.h(113) : error C2228: left of '.getEnergyPerRequest' must have class/struct/union type
MySBBModule.h(116) : error C2065: 'pSBBList' : undeclared identifier
MySBBModule.h(116) : error C2227: left of '->prepSBBAll' must point to class/struct/union
```

When I tried to do it in private section, I get the following errors:

```
MySBBModule.h(106) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'pSBBList2'
MySBBModule.h(113) : error C2228: left of '.getEnergyPerRequest' must have class/struct/union type
MySBBModule.h(116) : error C2065: 'pSBBList' : undeclared identifier
MySBBModule.h(116) : error C2227: left of '->prepSBBAll' must point to class/struct/union
```

PS: I have  **marked the line no** in the code that I am posting.

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards,
DK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the below is *declaring a function*:

```
SeqBuildBlockIRns myIRns_3(pSBBList2);
```

What you want to do is declare a member:

```
SeqBuildBlockIRns myIRns_3;
```

And then in your constructor construct it with the argument `pSBBList2`:

```
MySeqBuildBlockModule (SBBList* pSBBList0, long TI1_In, long TI2_In)    // more arguements in this constructor of derived class
: SeqBuildBlock (pSBBList0),
  myIRns_3(pSBBList2)  // <- construct
{ }
```

Comment: The reason, I can not do :SeqBuildBlockIRns myIRns_3; is because only one constructor is defined in third party header file which is SeqBuildBlockIRns(SBBList* ); Since I do not have access to CPP file, I can not modify their constructor.

Comment: What does that have to do with *declaring a member* of that type? Do you *understand* what the above syntax means in C++?

Comment: Thanks Nim, it worked. Thanks for clarifying my confusion. Whenever I was declaring the member, I was always initializing it as it was giving me error: SeqBuildBlockIRns myIRns_3(pSBBList2);